# Mongoose replace project with group

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have aggregated the results of 3 collections which are
User -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc425bb3e99c8269ce51faa"),
    "fname" : "Akash",
    "salary" : 25000,
    "age" : 23,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

dept -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc46167b365918881aa3bbf"),
    "fname" : "Akash",
    "dept" : "IT"
}
```

balance -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc4349adcc885e047054466"),
    "fname" : "Akash",
    "balance" : 4000
}
```

My Query To aggregate -

```
User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "balance",
        localField: "fname",
        foreignField: "fname",
        as: "result"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$result"
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "dept",
        localField: "fname",
        foreignField: "fname",
        as: "deptresult"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$deptresult"
    },
    {
      $project: {
        fname: 1,
        salary: 1,
        "result.balance": 1,
        "deptresult.dept": 1
      }
    }
  ]).exec((err, users) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(users);
  });
```

I am using mongoose and i want to replace my $project wit $group command and save the results to another collection. 
How can i achieve this?
expected op should contain
id,fname,salary,balance and dept

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the post ? What is the grouping key ?

Comment: Yes i have updated the qt